# Using Stripe Checkout, can I validate uniqueness of customer's email address on Stripe side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I want to validate uniqueness of a customer's email address, not inside my application, but in Stripe platform. Ideal behavior will be like this:

- Integrate Stripe Checkout to my website. ref) [Checkout Quickstart | Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout#integrate)
- Customer visits the website and proceeds to the payment URL (of Stripe domain).
- The customer fills the form with their email address and credit card information.
- If the email address is already used in Stripe customers, then the payment fails with an error.

I'm following the steps described in [Rails Checkout Guide \| Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails).

Comment: Hi @alea12, currently Stripe does not use email as unique identifier for customer. You will need to implement this yourself on your server side. Maintaining a map between email and stripe provided customer id (cus_xxxxx).

Comment: You will need to store the customer token in association to the users email address.  You can them relate them and do it through the token instead.  I do believe you can pass through extra data to stripe, but its mostly for your purposes only, not theirs.